# How can I replace the input directory by the output directory, when recursively traversing over the input directory?

Tags: shell

I want to write a script what recursively traverses over an input directory and for each file it generates a corresponding file under a separate directory hierarchy.

For example, file `input/a/b/c.txt` becomes `output/a/b/c.txt` and `input/a/d.txt` becomes `output/a/d.txt`. What is a clean way to replace the name of the input directory by the name of the output directory when I do this?

---

The two ways that I know don't feel right. The first is to use `#` parameter expansion to get rid of the file prefix. However, that does weird things if the name of the input directory has special characters like `*`. It also is hard to read if the name of input directory is in a variable.

```bsh
find input -type f | while read -r infile; do
    outfile=output/"${infile#input/}"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$outfile")"
    some-program "$infile" > "$outfile"
done
```

The other thing that I tried is to cd to the input directory and use absolute links for everything. However, that requires multiple calls to `cd` and also depends on `readlink`, which isn't the most portable.

```bsh
abspwd=$(pwd)
absinput=$(readlink -f input)
absoutput=$(readlink -f output)

cd "$absinput"
find . -type f | while read infile; do
    outfile="$absoutput/$infile"
    mkdir -p "$(dirname "$outfile")"
    some-program "$infile" > "$outfile"
done
cd "$abspwd"
```

Is there another way? It feels like there ought to be a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.

I'll place an rsync which will replicate just the directory structure of input in output. Thhen when your find-while pipe runs it will throw the output of some-program in the right places.

```
TOP="input"
rsync -a -f'+ */' -f'- *' "$TOP"/  output/
find "$TOP" -type f | while IFS= read -r infile; do
    outfile=output/${infile#"$TOP"/}
    some-program "$infile" > "$outfile"
done
```

Note file names with newlines will not be treated properly. If you feel that scenario is warranted then they can be handled with some more code. I didn't want to distract from the issue you had namely of migrating file names from one dir to another.

Comment: That's an interisting suggestion of how to avoid the mkdir. But the part I was more worried abou was how to get the name of the outfile. IIRC, the prefix-removal via parameter expansion can do weird things if the directory name has special characters.

Comment: There will not be any issues with weird looking names. Since they are not exposed to the shell. You may try running this and see for your self.

Comment: IIRC, the part to the right of the `#` is treated like a glob, so characters like `*` have a special meaning.

Comment: Sure. But escaping can get awkward if the directory name is stored in a variable... In the original script I'm working with, all the directory names come from user input.

Comment: So if that is the case then silence the glob chars by placing them in square brackets.Alternatively, `set -f` to disable globbing in the duration of the while loop

Comment: Then place the input top dir name in double quotes so that globbing is inhibited. Did you try the set -f?